# PPA too slow, how to mirror? [Cache repository subset]

Tags: apt, ppa

I have to install graphic drivers on tens/hundreds of computers, and PPA graphics-drivers just drops download speed to a few kB/s, which means it would take days or more to install all that.

One solution would be to download the packages, and manually install everything. Another one would be to create a proxy that redirects the requested packages to some local copy.

What is the proper way of solving this? I've seen a few topics complaining about launchpad availability, and I'm in Western China where I can't rely on having a nice fast connection.

Edit: I was looking for a caching solution, that doesn't involve having a full repository when I only need a fraction of several repositories. Problem solved with apt-cacher-ng which only caches what is downloaded and doesn't require mirroring full repositories.

Comment: I used `apt-cacher-ng` before. Maybe you can make it work...

Comment: Yes, apt-cacher-ng was indeed the way to go, found a mention in the (erroneously) duplicate topic. Decided to cache everything by the way, speeds up the whole process without needing much space on my apt cache.

Comment: Isn't anybody offering mirror in different geo localization?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future viewers, the solution was using **apt-cacher-ng**. [Following this blog post](https://fabianlee.org/2018/02/11/ubuntu-a-centralized-apt-package-cache-using-apt-cacher-ng/) I created an APT cache that I added as proxy on each machine to update. On first download, a packet would be stored in the cache which would make subsequent downloads as fast as the network/disk allowed.

Contrarily to the popular answer to make a full mirror, I didn't have to download any package not related to me, such as the full repository. Didn't have to worry about what was exactly needed since only what was requested would be cached.